# S3 upload succeeds with CLI and Console but throws Acces Denied through SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I am able to upload a file to my s3 bucket through the AWS console and cli but getting access denied through the sdk. Calling `aws sts get-caller-identity` from the cli and `sts.getCallerIdentity()` from within the code I can confirm the same set of credentials are being used to perform the action.

The upload code is as follows:

```
    const aws = require("aws-sdk");
    const s3 = new aws.S3();
    const sts = new aws.STS();

    sts.getCallerIdentity({}, (err, data) => {
        // matches result from aws sts get-caller-identity
        console.log(data);
    });

    let bucket = {
        Bucket: "my-bucket",
        Key: "user@email.com/uuid/Submitted_Put.csv",
        Body: "col1,col2,col3\nval1,val2,val3",
        Tagging: "TEMPLATE_NAME=my_template_v1.0",
        ServerSideEncryption: "aws:kms",
    };
    s3.putObject(bucket)
        .promise()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data.Key);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: Are you supplying a KMS key ID when using the awscli?

Comment: No I'm not. For good measure I did try supplying the KMS Key ID in the code before and it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this ended up being a permission problem with setting the tagging key of the bucket object. Apparently the execution policy required additional `s3:putObjectTagging` action to be allowed.